# Distance between evolute of $\alpha$ and $\alpha$

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to solve this exercise, can someone give me a hint?

Let $ \alpha : I \subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ a arc length parametrization of a curve and $\kappa(s)$, the curvature at $\alpha(s)$ is positive and nondecreasing.

Let $\beta$ be $\alpha$ 's evolute.

For $x \in I$ show that

$$
 | \alpha(s) - \beta(x)| \leq \frac{1}{\kappa(x)},
$$

for all $s \in I, s \geq x$.

---

Geometrically it seems right, since $|\alpha(s) - \beta(s)| = \frac{1}{\kappa(s)}$, which means that the distance between $\alpha(s)$ and $\beta(s)$ is the radius $\frac{1}{\kappa(s)}$ of a circle.

And thus, $|\alpha(t) - \beta(t)|$ as $t$ increases, are decreasing radius of circles.

So $|\alpha(s) - \beta(x)|$ is a "diagonal" of a rectangle, with opposite sides of $\frac{1}{\kappa(x)}$ and $\frac{1}{\kappa(s)}$.

Comment: What is $\kappa$? Is it curvature?

Comment: Yes, $\kappa(s)$ the curvature at $\alpha(s)$.

Comment: Yes, $\beta(s)$ is defined as $\beta(s) = \alpha(s) + \frac{1}{\kappa(s)} n(s)$. And it's easy to prove that $|\alpha(s) - \beta(s)| \leq \frac{1}{\kappa(s)}$. But I have to prove it for a $x \leq s$

Comment: Yes, the proof is that $|\alpha(\textbf{s}) - \beta(\textbf{x})| \leq \frac{1}{\kappa(x)} $, being $x \leq s$. From what I understood, the exercise states that, choosing $x \in I$, the distance of the evolute at $x$ and any point in $\alpha$ with parameter $s \geq x$ is less then or equal the inverse of the curvature in $x$

Comment: Are you sure that the curvature in your example is increasing? Isn't equal $2$ for $x=0$ and decreasing?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\beta(s)=\alpha(s)+\frac{1}{\kappa(s)}n(s)$ be the evolute curve and $t(s)=\alpha'(s)$ the tangent vector. Note that $$\beta'(s)=t(s)+\frac{-\kappa(s)^2t(s)-\kappa'(s)n(s)}{\kappa(s)^2}=\frac{-\kappa'(s)}{\kappa(s)^2}n(s).$$

Therefore, the arclength of the evolute curve between two point $\beta(t_1)$, $\beta(t_2)$ is given by $$\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\frac{\kappa'(s)}{\kappa(s)^2}ds=-\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\left(\frac{1}{\kappa(s)}\right)'ds=R_1-R_2,$$

where $R_1=1/\kappa(t_1)$ and $R_2=1/\kappa(t_2)$. Note that $R_1,R_2$ are the radius of curvature from the osculate circle, hence, as $R_1\ge R_2$, we conclude that the circle with radius $R_2$ is contained in the closed ball, which boundary is the circle with radius $R_1$.

Now, it remains to prove that if the curvature is positive nondeacreasing, and if $C_x$ is the osculate circle at the point $x$, then the curve must enter (or stay) in the the osculate circle $C_x$ for $s\ge x$. You can achieve it by using Taylor formula.

Comment: I don't get how you got: $\beta'(s)=t(s)+\frac{-\kappa(s)^2t(s)-\kappa'(s)n(s)}{\kappa(s)^2} = \frac{-\kappa'(s)}{\kappa(s)^2}n(s)$. Since $d/ds (\frac{1}{\kappa(s)}n(s)) = \frac{\kappa(s)n'(s) - \kappa'(s)n(s)}{k(s)^2}$

Comment: In my choice of orientation, we have that $t'(s)=\kappa(s)n(s)$ and $n'(s)=-\kappa(s)t(s)$.

Answer (score 0):

It's trivial from the geometric point of view!

Imagine a circle C. It radius is $1/k(x)$. It center is $\beta (x)$. And our curve L touches C in point $\alpha (x)$. So because curvature of L is positive and nondecreasing L must lie inside circle C for all $s > x$. That is a distance from center of circle C to a next point $\alpha (s)$ of curve L which is equals to
$|\beta(x) - \alpha (s)|$ must be less than circle radius:
$$|\beta(x) - \alpha (s)| \le \frac{1}{k(x)}$$

Thus, in language of formulas you get your inequality! That's all.